# How could I translate "一语道破", "一语道破天机"

Tags: translation

I want translate "一语道破" or "一语道破天机" to a phase with an etymology.

tell the truth, blurts out the whole truth,

seem not very good.

Comment: It's not "blurt out", but "get the exact point" of something. It's pretty close to the phrase: "hit the nail (right) on the head" in English. Perhaps not that exactly, but the underlying connotation is similar.

Comment: 'hit the nail on the head'  is '一矢中的' in Chinese, meaning  'find exactly the right answer'

Comment: @TangHo, It's a figure of speech. It could be extended more than that. *state the truth exactly; find exactly the right answer; and etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一语 = in one sentence or one word (*imply: 'directly and swiftly'*)

道破 = pointing out/ expose (*speak out and expose something that's hidden*)

一语道破 can be described as "directly (and swiftly) pointing out" in English

Example:

- 道破他的詭計 =  speak out and expose his trickery
- 道破他的用心 =  pointing out his intention
- 一语道破他的詭計 = directly (and swiftly) pointing out his trickery
- 一语道破他的用心 = directly (and swiftly) pointing out his intention

“一语道破天机” is not a proper sentence, because '天机' (heaven's secret/ plan) is not something you can easily find out.

Comment: 一语道破天机 is a common metaphor, you can't take it literally at all.

Comment: 一语道破 and 天机不可洩漏 are both common phrases, but not together

Comment: try to make a little search on 一语道破天机, and you would get lots of examples and explainations.

Comment: garbage in, garbage out, Someone mixed up 一语道破 and 天机不可洩漏 , someone else tried to make sense of it , then  someone else copied these so call answers and they all became search results

Comment: I knew 一语道破天机 since I was a little boy. It's actually very common. You could take anything people are saying as garbage if you wish. That's it.

Comment: Internet search results are not always correct, Sometimes a movies or TV. show using a common phrase as title, and you can't find the real meaning of that common phrase anymore, sometimes a famous people misuse an idiom, and people would think the wrong meaning is legit--My advice is use some independent thinking when reviewing the so call 'answers'

Comment: It's actually very common? I lived for 50+ years, read hundred of thousands of articles , not to mention countless movies and TV and I've never seen anyone mix these two phrase like this

Comment: Maybe, it's regional and also depends on what kind of stuff you have read. I personally read and heard a lot of it, TV, movie, newspaper, and pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest "freudian slip"

if it's fate, destiny related, maybe "oracle slip", or "divine slip"

in which slip referred to the "一語"

have fun :)

Comment: No, "freudian slip" (an unintentional error regarded as revealing subconscious feelings) it means someone carelessly mention something that should be kept secret. It is  called 說漏嘴